# Generic Class with a non generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the next interface:

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
  string Message { set; get; }
}
```

My generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface 
{
  public T item;
  public string Message{ set; get; }
}
```

I need cast between different generic classes for example:

```
MyClass<String> myClassString = new MyClass<String>();
MyClass<Boolean> myClassBoolean = new MyClass<Boolean>();


myClassString  =  (IMyInterface)myClassBoolean; //This code not working.
myClassString = (MyClass<String>)(IMyInterface)myClassBoolean // This code working.
```

My question is, why in the first case my code is not working and in the second case my code is working? What is the best method to do this?

Comment: The error messages you're getting in each case will tell you exactly why the code isn't working.

Comment: The second one is not going to produce a compiler error, but the cast will fail at run time, so "working" is not exactly an accurate description.

Comment: @mikez Yes, but I performed the following operation:  myClassString = (MyClass<Boolean>)(IMyInterface)myClassBoolean ; if (myClassBoolean.Item) myClassString.Item = "Hola";, in this case the code working, right?, but what is the best method to do this?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing yourself with generics. In this context you might as well use two completely different classes.

Comment: @Chiro300 No, that won't work at all.

Comment: You insist on asking "what is the best method to do this" but it is not at all clear what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast down to an interface, but a common interface will not allow you to cast between generic types.

In your case, you can not go from boolean to string, but you would be able to do this:

```
  IMyInterface x = new MyClass<String>();
  IMyInterface y = new MyClass<Boolean>();

  x = y;
```